# Xcode 3.1: where to download?

Tags: xcode, macos

it appears that the Apple site now only provides download for Xcode 3.2, that is the Snow Leopard version. I'm running Leopard, and the installation doesn't work. Where to find previous versions? Thanks

Comment: I have an Xcode 3.1.4 dmg, I can share it if anybody still needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Xcode 3.1.3 Developer Tools download at [developer.apple.com/downloads/](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/mac/

You can register for a free ADC online membership. After you are registered you can download Xcode.

Comment: i know, but the site only lets me download 3.2 and not 3.1, that's the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Xcode from your Leopard CDs, or you can download the Leopard iPhone SDK which comes with Xcode.

Comment: Hi,
I don't have any Leopard CD. My new MacBook Pro came with Leopard pre-installe AND the DVD of Snow Leopard in the package! Plus, I'm not interested in Iphone Developement, but in Mac-Cocoa

Comment: Downloading the iPhone SDK will give you XCode, which will allow you do Mac/Cocoa development (The iPhone SDK is the full development environment + the iPhone stuff).